# Windows option is missing in Dual boot Grub loader

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, grub, multi-boot

I installed Windows 7 and then Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop. After installing, when I restart, GRUB didn't load. Instead, it straight away went to Windows booting as if there's Only windows available on my HDD. I thought there's a problem with GRUB loader. So, with the help of Boot-Repair software, through Ubuntu live mode, I reinstalled GRUB. When I restart, GRUB Loader is loading but without Windows 7 option. Please let me know where it went wrong? MY boot-repair log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5616550/

Answer (score 0):

Pop in a live cd and navigate (usually) to `/boot/grub/grub.conf`for grub `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` for grub2

Manual add this to your config file

```
menuentry "Windows 7" {
   set root=(hdX,Y)
   chainloader +1
}
```

Where X=drive#, Y=partition#.

From your log it appears you have multiple partitions that could hold windows
the above should be equal to one of these

- (hd0,2) <-- this is my bet though
- (hd0,3)
- (hd1,1)